# DOMDocument::loadHTML(): input conversion failed due to input error

Tags: php, parsing, dom, curl, web-scraping

I am looking to scrap a **Chinese website** using **PHP** and **CURL**. Earlier I had an issue with the compressed results and SO had helped me to sort it out.
Now I'm facing a trouble while parsing the contents through **PHP - DOMDocument**.
The error is as follows,

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xE3 0x80 0x90 0xE8 in /var/www/html/ ..
```

Even though warning this is preventing from getting further results.

My code is as given below:

```
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0';
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('text/html; charset=gb2312')); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");  // handling all compressions 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
$html = curl_exec($curl) or die("error: ".curl_error($curl));
curl_close($curl);
$htmlParsed = mb_convert_encoding($result,'utf-8','gb2312');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlParsed);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@class="test"]//a/@href');

if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";

    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

I found the content type in my target website as ,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
```

So I tried converting result to utf-8.

Since the input conversion fails at 'DOMDocument::loadHTML()' line of the code ,I can't parse the web page to get the results.
I am currently stuck at this point and any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanx in advance.

*(Earlier I used to work with simple HTML DOM parser,which was pretty simple.But later after reading the cons in SO regarding its usage.I planned to switch to PHP's native DOM Parser )*

Comment: Try to suppress errors while loading the HTML, i.e. `@$doc->loadHTML($htmlParsed);`, this is maybe the only time when suppressing errors is acceptable, because the PHP DOM is very, very pernickety and try not to convert the page, just load it as it is, then try to eliminate the next issue (if any).

Comment: Yes,I had tried suppressing the errors,but it could not yield me the results.

Comment: Check also your `XPath` query, try to get something very simple, then move on to the next element.

Comment: @bodi0 Yes ,I tried with some very simple tags.But no luck.! :(

Comment: Read about this (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47108&edit=3) PHP bug, which version of PHP you use? And, you can try PHP tidy (http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php)

Comment: @bodi0 Im using PHP Version 5.3.3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51680/discussion-between-surabhil-and-bodi0)

Answer (score 3):

I see a solution today .

```
$html=new DOMDocument();  
$html_source    = get_html();
$html_source    =mb_convert_encoding( $html_source, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
$html->loadHTML( $html_source );
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the full head of the document that you are parsing I can only guess, but if the  with the character encoding data does not come directly after the  tag, you may be running into a situation where DomDocument is using its default of ISO-8859-1 and running into the【 character (the first three "invalid" bytes in gb2312) of which the 0x80 byte would be the first bit of nonsense since this is an unused code point in ISO-8859-1. This would likely trigger the bug in DomDocument discussed in the comments above. And could easily happen if the  element is included before the content-type meta information.

The only thing I can think of to try would be to run the html through a bit of prep and move that content-type meta tag to right after the  tag to try to make it use the correct character set. If you use mb_convert_encoding or iconv to convert the encoding to iso-5589-1 or utf-8, make sure that you modify the meta information because DomDocument is, unfortunately, brittle in many ways.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('xml.xml');
function convert_utf8( $string ) { 
    if ( strlen(utf8_decode($string)) == strlen($string) ) {   
        // $string is not UTF-8
        return iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $string);
    } else {
        // already UTF-8
        return $string;
    }
}

$contents = mb_convert_encoding( $contents, mb_detect_encoding($contents), "UTF-8");

$xml = simplexml_load_string(convert_utf8($contents));
print_r($xml);
```